# how to pop all Async tasks on device Home button click

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-asynctask

I Want to stop all the async tasks on the device home button press, but the problem is when progress dialog is running, on home button click only the progress dialog kills and it does goto the onKeyDown() method where i have mentioned the logic to kill my async tasks. So async task runs in the background even after the application is closed and my app crashed. Is there any solution to close the progress dialog as well as all async tasks on home button click

Answer (score 1):

In java, we can't stop a `Thread` which has been started and is running. So is the `AsyncTask`

but you can try call `asyncTask.cancel()` which works like `thread.interrupt()`. It may throw an `InterruptedException`. If there exists more code behind, these code will execute as well, so take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't intercept calls to the home button directly.Though when the home button is pressed onPause() will be called, so you can override that method and put your logic there.

Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle for more info

Comment: Actually the problem is While the progress Dialog is running and i press the home button, onKeyDown() does not capture key press, it just close the progress dialog, so is there any way to override the progress dialog.